# While loop with users input

Tags: loops, python-3.4

I am trying to ask the user 2 questions. They are supposed to answer numbers greater than 0, but if they answer something like 1,0 or maybe 0,1 that is still a valid answer. If they answer both questions with 0's then the program is to terminate. Where am I going wrong here because I have been stuck on this for over an hour.

```
a = 1
b = 1

while a > 0 and b > 0:

    a = float(input("Enter A: "))
    b = float(input("Enter B: "))

    if a > 0 and b > 0:

        #calculate equations here
        #calculate equations here

        #print responses here
        #print responses here

    elif a == 0 and b == 0:

        print("Good bye!")
```

Comment: It is supposed to loop around if both "a" and "b" do not equal 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think what you are looking for is something like

```
a = 1
b = 1

while a > 0 or b > 0:

    a = float(input("Enter A: "))
    b = float(input("Enter B: "))

    if a == 0 and b == 0:
        print("Good bye!")
    else:
        #calculate equations here
        #calculate equations here

        #print responses here
        #print responses here
```